# How to count the number of instances of various strings in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a large dictionary (10,000+ entries) of ReviewIDs.  The dictionary has two keys, the first is the ReviewID # and the second is the language of the Review.

My task is to compute the total # of reviews in each language and then display it in a bar plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
RevDict = {}
with open('ReviewID.txt','r') as f:
for line in f:
    a,b = line.split(":")
    RevDict[a] = str(b)
```

This results in a dictionary that looks like this:

[image]

My idea, was to convert the dictionary into a Dataframe with the Review ID being one column and the language being a second column.  I could then iterate through the rows using a counter and end up with a final count for each language.  This could easily be converted into a bar plot.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this.

I also suspect that the more pythonic approach would be to simply count the # of instances of each string within the dictionary itself rather than going through the step of making a dataframe.  I tried this:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(k['b'] for k in data if k.get('b'))
```

It is throwing the following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter`

```
import collections as coll

data = {
  'A': 'English',
  'B': 'German',
  'C': 'English'
} 

print(coll.Counter(data.values()))

--output:--
Counter({'English': 2, 'German': 1})
```

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': 'fr\n',
    'B': 'de\n',
    'C': 'fr\n',
    'D': 'de\n',
    'E': 'fr\n',
    'F': 'en\n'
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': list(data.keys()),
        'lang': [val.rstrip() for val in data.values()],
    }
)

print(df)
```

output:

```
  id lang
0  B   de
1  A   fr
2  F   en
3  D   de
4  E   fr
5  C   fr
```

---

```
grouped = df.groupby('lang')
print(grouped.size())
```

output:

```
lang
de    2
en    1
fr    3
```

---

**Response to comment**

`Plotting`:

```
import collections as coll
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

data = {
    'A': 'fr\n',
    'B': 'de\n',
    'C': 'fr\n',
    'D': 'de\n',
    'E': 'fr\n',
    'F': 'en\n'
}

counter = coll.Counter(
    [val.rstrip() for val in data.values()]
)

langs, lang_counts = zip(
    *sorted(counter.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
)
total_langs = sum(lang_counts)

bar_heights = np.array(lang_counts, dtype=float) / total_langs
x_coord_left_side_of_bars = np.arange(len(langs))
bar_width = 0.8

plt.bar(
    x_coord_left_side_of_bars,
    bar_heights,
    bar_width,
)

plt.xticks(  
    x_coord_left_side_of_bars + (bar_width * 0.5),  #position of tick marks
    langs  #labels for tick marks
)
plt.xlabel('review language')
plt.ylabel('% of all reviews')

x = plt.plot()
#plt.show()  #Can use show() instead of savefig() until everything works correctly
plt.savefig('lang_plot.png')
```

plot:

[image]

Comment: The dictionary method using collections.Counter worked.  I now have an output that appears to be a dictionary listing the various languages with the number of instances in descending order.  The final step is that I need to get this into a bar graph showing the % of reviews represented by each language.  I assume this is a matplotlib function, but I'm unclear on how to pull the data from the dictionary to create this graph.

Comment: @AndrewSmith, A Counter is unordered, which means you can't count on any specific ordering of the keys.  See matplotlib example at bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for k in data` loop, each `k` is a string key (the review id). Strings have no `.get()` method, nor does the original variable `b` have any bearing on this loop.

If you wanted to count the values, just pass the values of the dictionary straight to the `Counter`:

```
Counter(data.values())
```

You probably want to remove the newline characters first:

```
for line in f:
    review_id, lang = line.split(":")
    RevDict[review_id] = lang.strip()
```